# Не могу авторизировать поле @Autowired

Tags: java, mysql, spring

**Код:**

```html
package backend.dao;

import backend.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u where u.name = :name")
    User findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

---

```html
package backend.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String correctPassword;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCorrectPassword() {
        return correctPassword;
    }

    public void setCorrectPassword(String correctPassword) {
        this.correctPassword = correctPassword;
    }

  }
```

---

```html
package backend.service;

import backend.model.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {

    User addUser(User user);
    void delete(long id);
    User getByName(String name);
    User editUser(User user);
    List<User> getAll();
}
```

---

```html
package backend.service.implementation;

import backend.dao.UserRepository;
import backend.model.User;
import backend.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getByName(String name) {
        return userRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public User editUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

**applicationContext.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="backend.*"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

</beans>
```

---

**dispatecher-servlet.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="backend"/>


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

**appconfig-data.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
   </bean>
```

**Ошибка:**

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'backend.dao.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Если в классе UserServiceImpl у поля снизу убрать @Autowired, то все будет работать. В чем моя ошибка?

```html
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Component-scan срабатывает только на аннотированные классы/интерфейсы. 
Интерфейс который расширяет JpaRepository должен быть аннотирован @Repository только после этого сработает любой component-scan, также, хоть это интерфейс, но все же нужно указывать в названии репозитория Impl, то есть в вашем случае будет UserRepositoryImpl

Comment: Как указать в название репозитория UserRepositoryImpl?

Comment: Извините ночью писал, теперь поправил ответ

Answer (score -1):

Нужно в appconfig-data.xml добавить

```
 <jpa:repositories base-package="backend.dao" />
```

Подробнее, см док-цию на [JPA Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories)

Comment: Появились вот такие ошибки: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Mar 31 17:28:23 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy.

Comment: Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V